# Properties of vectors which are not in nullspace or rowspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose i have matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \ 0 \ 1 \\ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$ Basis for the $\eta(A)$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}.$

What about vectors which not in the row space and not in the nullspace like $v^T = \begin{bmatrix}  1 \ 1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$ Do they possess any intresting properties? Something intresting about them?

Comment: I think it is much more interesting to see the set of vectors that ARE in the nullspace. That has applications in linear algebra and in general in math. For example creating an orthogonal set of vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such vectors can be decomposed into a sum of vectors from the row and nullspace. For example,

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \frac{-1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -2\end{pmatrix} + \frac{3}{5}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

In general, the nullspace and the rowspace are orthogonal, and even if the actual rows are not orthogonal (w.r.t. one another), you can still choose an orthogonal basis for the rowspace (likewise for the nullspace), so you can always make this decomposition orthogonal.

Comment: "Such vectors can be decomposed into a sum of vectors" - all i needed, Thanks!